# Parsing a float number from JSON using nlohmann::json

Tags: c++, json, nlohmann-json

I want to get a decimal number from a json file into a float variable by using the nlohmann::json library and allways get the output 86700.2031 instead of 86700.2. First I used a numeric json type:

```
{
  "test": 86700.2,
}
```

and tried this way:

```
using json = nlohmann::json;
std::string config_path = "C:/config/default.json";
std::ifstream config_file(config_path);
json config = json::parse(config_file);

float test = config["test"]; //Output: 86700.2031
```

After that I changed the json type to string and tried this with the same outcome:

```
float test = std::stof(config["test"].get<std::string>()); //Output: 86700.2031
```

Reading integers or strings works fine. How do I read a float value properly?

Comment: See "Notes regarding precision of floating-point numbers" of https://json.nlohmann.me/features/types/number_handling/ Also, try using double or long double instead of float.

Comment: single precision only has about 7 decimal digits of precision, youre seeing rounding errors which arent specifically related to nlohmann::json. if you used `double` you'd' get ~15 digits of precison *but you are still prone to rounding errors*. If you cant live with rounding errors you will need to use a non-floating point type

Comment: Unfortunately I dont understand the related article completely. I tried to apply it like this: test = (std::numeric_limits<double>::max_digits10, config["test"]); but still get the same problem. The number still isn't rounded in my understanding. It just added digits to my number. Isnt't there anything I cant do against it?

Comment: It is rounded, but not in 10-base digit system. 86700.2 is too big number for float to handle without visible error. Floating numbers cannot always express exact decimal numbers. Just switch to double for now (even thought double will have the same rounding issue, but with much bigger values).

Comment: If you can use a different JSON library and performance is of concern, you may consider using SIMDJson. It is, to my knowledge, the fastest JSON parsing library right now (according to their benchmarks 25 times faster than nlohmann). https://github.com/simdjson/simdjson

Answer (score 0):

"float" has very low precision. Never use float but use double instead. (One day you will know where you can go against that advice. Before that, use double). The result will not be exactly 86700.2 but very close to it.

Weird though that your library returns a string when the value clearly isn't a string. I'd check the documentation for what function you should call. You should never have to convert data yourself like that.

Answer (score 0):

As per the official docs of the nlohmann library, this is an inherent property of the library:

> floating-point numbers are rounded to the nearest double and serialized with the shortest representation to allow round-tripping

Easier to understand with the quoted e.g.

```cpp
float f = 0.3;
json j = f;
std::cout << j << '\n'; // yields 0.30000001192092896.
```

So in short, the float/double numbers are rounded to the max digits possible in the datatype.

There is no solution to this other than changing your datatype to `std::string` or moving to another (above-mentioned) alternatives.